# Drawing Phase Portrait of Differential equations using polar coordinates

Tags: polar-coordinates, nonlinear-system

I'm currently taking a course in nonlinear dynamics and I am having a bit trouble drawing phase portraits on polar coordinates.

I solved systems of nonlinear equations by doing polar substitution,

\begin{align}
      \dot{x} &= -y + ax(x^2 + y^2) \\
      \dot{y} &=  x + ay(x^2 + y^2)
    \end{align}

I got this after..
   \begin{align}
      \dot{r} &= ar^3 \\
      \dot{\theta} &= 1
    \end{align}

I have hard time understand how to draw a phase portrait for a question like this by hand. I understand the radial motion is dependent on a. For even for a simple example when a = 0, I'm not sure how to approach it.

Since \begin{align}\dot{r} = 0\end{align} this indicates that the distance from the origin is constant on time, which would indicate a circular orbit. I'm not really sure how to interpret the second equation though...

Edit: Some intuition on how the distance changes as a varies would also be really helpful!

Thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $a=0$ your phase portrait would look sort of like a "hurricane" with its eye at the origin. That is no trajectory would get further or closer to the origin but they would all be rotating with the same angular speed. More interesting things happen when we consider a system with more varying of $r$. In the vicinity of a stable, fixed point of $r$ trajectories would look like spirals approaching $r=r^{*}$ (the $r$-fixed point or limit cycle). This picture is the phase portrait for $\dot{r}=r\sin(r)$ and $\dot{\theta}=1$. Notice that for fixed points $r=2n\pi$ the trajectories "sprial out" of the limit cycle such as at $r=0$. But for the stable fixed points of $r$ (that is $r=2n\pi +\pi$) the trajectories spiral inwards.  Hopefully, this answers your question.

[image: Plot for $\dot{\theta}=1 \dot{r}=r\sin(r)]